# Start background service from foreground service in android O

Tags: android, service

Can I start background service from foreground service in android O, is it a good practice, and can work fine as long as the application installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An app is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following is true:

- It has a foreground service.

The [documents](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) said if your application already has `foreground service` it means your app is running on the foreground so that you can start `background service`.